# Apache Camel escape double Curly Brackets

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-camel

i am using Apache Camel and I have an endpoint that contains double curly brackets.

```
For example: " endpoint {{ valueToBeOverriden }}".
```

When I call the following statement, it throws a ResolveEndpointFailedException.

```
camelContext.getEndpoint(" endpoint {{ valueToBeOverriden }}")
```

I noticed the problem are the double curly brackets: **{{**.

How can I escape them?
Do you have any idea?

Thank you,
Luisa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you created a PropertiesComponent for your Camel Context?

For example:

#### Configuring PropertiesComponent in Spring XML

```
<camelContext ...>
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="com/mycompany/myprop.properties"/>
</camelContext>
```

You can visit http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html for more information.